# javascript - join 2 buttons in 1

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that loads an 'iframe' and another one that closes, and I would like to merge the two functions into one button.
I do not know if this is possible.
I would like someone to help me.

```
<button class="hashtag" id="load">PLAY</button>
<button class="hashtag" onclick="parent.closeIFrame();">STOP</button>
```

```html
<button class="hashtag" id="load">PLAY</button>
<!--<iframe id="myFrame" scrolling="no" src="https://www.rtp.pt/play/popup/antena3#player_prog" style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>-->
<button class="hashtag" onclick="parent.closeIFrame();">STOP</button>

<script>
  function closeIFrame() {
    $('#myFrame').remove();
  }
</script>


<div id="iframeHolder" style="opacity:0;width:0;height:0;"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#load').click(function() {
      $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="myFrame" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://example" style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep both but show one based on conditions.

Comment: Yes, it's an idea, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just made it into one button and changed the text to STOP once its clicked, also toggling a variable keeping track of whether or not the iFrame is loaded.  If it is clicked when it says STOP is runs the close function and toggles it back to PLAY.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hashtag" id="load">PLAY</button>

<div id="iframeHolder" style="opacity:0;width:0;height:0;"></div> 
<script>

  var loaded = false;
  $(function(){
      $('#load').click(function(){ 
          if (!loaded) {
            $('#load').text("STOP")
            $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="myFrame" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://example" style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>');
            loaded = true;
          } else {
            $('#load').text("PLAY")
            $('#myFrame').remove();
            loaded = false;
          }
      });   
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".play").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("play close");
      $(".hidden").toggleClass("show hidden");

      if($(this).hasClass("close")){
        $(this).html("CLOSE");
        $("iframe").css({"display" : "block"})
      }else{
        $(this).html("PLAY");
        $("iframe").css({"display" : "none"})
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.play{
  color: black;
}
.close{
  color: red;
}
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="play">PLAY</button>
<iframe class="hidden"></iframe>
```

Tell me if it works for you